How to interpret Safe revertReason?
I'm calling a smart contract I made using a Safe Smart Account (with permissionless + Privy), and when I execute a call I see that the UserOp was reverted with a revertReason of 7FCDD1F4. I have no idea how to interpret this, and I was not able to convert this to a string. Would love any feedback on how to debug further.
Here is the link to the Sepolia Base transaction for more context.

When analysing the transaction on Tenderly, we can get more information about the callstack and where exactly the transaction failed. Here it seems that the contract SemaphoreVerifier makes the transaction revert with comments Either proof or verification key is invalid. It is not strictly related to a problem with Safe, but you can still explore the rest of the call stack (and in particular the contracts tab) to gain more insights on what could have gone wrong.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
